# How to specify version in only one place when using pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, version, dry, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

My package version is defined in two places:

- `__version__ = 1.2.3` in `mypackage/__init__.py`
- `version = "1.2.3"` in `pyproject.toml` (I am using Poetry)

I have to update both whenever I bump the version which is annoying and not DRY. Is there a way to make Python read the version from the TOML, or to make the TOML read the version from Python?

Comment: You sniffed something fishy and you were right. Why would you need another place to track your project's metadata if you already use `pyproject.toml`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

After you have installed your project - either in editable mode by `poetry install` or from the wheel - you can access several metadata via `importlib.metadata` (`importlib_metadata` for python < 3.8).

So keep the version only in the `pyproject.toml` and use this in your python code:

```py
import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version("mypackage")
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, where would I find this information in the docs? https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#version is quite terse.

Comment: This works quite well until it runs in a GitLab pipeline. Any clues on how to do this *without* the ability to install the package?

Answer (score 15):

This code worked for me:

```
import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib_metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)
```

However, this only works if the package is already **installed using pip or poetry**.

On newer version (dot instead of underscore):

```
__version__ = importlib.metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)
```

Comment: would this work for editable installs? from what i am seeing when editable install and change version in pyproject.toml wouldnt be reflected?

Comment: @kamster it _is_ reflected, but only after re-running `pip install -Ue [package name]`, as far as I've been able to tell.

Comment: @haliphax that is what i noticed as well, but doesnt requiring to run upgrade install bit counter what editable install is meant to be (where thought one of goals would be you editable install once, otherwise if have to run install upgrade each time make change like this what is difference - again know this limited to changes in pyproject.toml). i could be misunderstanding expectations of editable install though

Answer (score 7):

Maybe overly complicated, but in order to not confuse an installed version of a package with an instance lingering around locally I use this code:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
import importlib.metadata
from pathlib import Path


def extract_version() -> str:
    """Returns either the version of installed package or the one
    found in nearby pyproject.toml"""
    with suppress(FileNotFoundError, StopIteration):
        with open((root_dir := Path(__file__).parent.parent)
                  / "pyproject.toml", encoding="utf-8") as pyproject_toml:
            version = (
                next(line for line in pyproject_toml if line.startswith("version"))
                .split("=")[1]
                .strip("'\"\n ")
            )
            return f"{version}-dev (at {root_dir})"
    return importlib.metadata.version(__package__
                                      or __name__.split(".", maxsplit=1)[0])

__version__ = extract_version()
```

Giving me either `1.2.23` for installed packages or something like `1.3.42-dev (at /project/location)`

Comment: This needs something `import`ed right?

Comment: `from contexlib import suppress` and `importlib`

Comment: [tomli](https://pypi.org/project/tomli/) would be a much better tool for doing this - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73902855/1785448)

Comment: that's right and you should do so if you don't want to avoid extra dependencies just for displaying a development-version

Comment: Clever solution but also somewhat dangerous.
The `__version__` variable may be consumed by build tools, too. Inserting a `-dev (at path/to/projectroot)` suffix may break the build in the best case (because it detects the PEP 440 violation, like pybuild does) or it may silently leak the suffix into production in the worst case.
A safer approach may be to have `extract_version()` return a clean version number without a suffix, and instead have your `--version` handler check for the presence of a `pyproject.toml` and do the work.

Answer (score 3):

All of the current answers address the issue of getting the version after install. However, as Jonathan Belden points out in a comment on [@finswimmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67097076/2364215), these methods break in CI pipelines and the like when the package isn't installed. In keeping with @z33k's comment on the question, one solution would be to read the value from `pyproject.toml`.

With [poetry](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/) as your package manager, another solution would be to use the [poetry-bumpversion](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-bumpversion/) plugin to manage version bumps using `poetry`'s `version` command. For example, say you have a package called `widget`, with `__version__` defined in `widget/__init__.py`, with the same value as `pyproject.toml` has for `version`. With the `poetry-bumpversion` plugin, you would add

```ini
[tool.poetry_bumpversion.file."widget/__init__.py"]
```

to `pyproject.toml`, then

```
% poetry version patch
Bumping version from 0.7.9 to 0.7.10
poetry_bumpversion: processed file widget/__init__.py

% git diff -U0
diff --git a/widget/__init__.py b/widget/__init__.py
index 18c7cbf..9ff9982 100644
--- a/widget/__init__.py
+++ b/widget/__init__.py
@@ -1 +1 @@
-__version__ = "0.7.9"
+__version__ = "0.7.10"
diff --git a/pyproject.toml b/pyproject.toml
index 1b86c6e..5de1ce1 100644
--- a/pyproject.toml
+++ b/pyproject.toml
@@ -3 +3 @@ name = "widget"
-version = "0.7.9"
+version = "0.7.10"
@@ -55,0 +56,2 @@ tox = "^4.6.4"
+[tool.poetry_bumpversion.file."widget/__init__.py"]
+
```

Answer (score 0):

I provided the answer to the same question in the [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100102/get-app-version-from-pyproject-toml-inside-python-code/78082532#78082532). Here is a copy:

---

In the `project.toml` you can specify version in different ways:

- [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/) expects version in the `[tool.poetry]`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
```

- [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) expects version in the `[project]` section:

```ini
[project]
name = "my-package"
version = "2020.0.0"
```

The next point is that you may want to see the version of installed packages (e.g. via `pip` or `poetry`) or your application. The next:

```py
import importlib.metadata

version = importlib.metadata.version("my-package")
print(version)
```

This code works fine with installed packages. To make working it with your project, you **should install** it using `pip install -e .` or something similar.

If you want to check version of your project **without installing**, then you can use the following snippet:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import toml

version = "unknown"
# adopt path to your pyproject.toml
pyproject_toml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "pyproject.toml"
if pyproject_toml_file.exists() and pyproject_toml_file.is_file():
    data = toml.load(pyproject_toml_file)
    # check project.version
    if "project" in data and "version" in data["project"]:
        version = data["project"]["version"]
    # check tool.poetry.version
    elif "tool" in data and "poetry" in data["tool"] and "version" in data["tool"]["poetry"]:
        version = data["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]
print(version)
```

To make it working you should install [`toml`](https://pypi.org/project/toml/) package in advance.