# How can use the 'version' specified in pyproject.toml file in my python typer program?

Tags: python, python-poetry

i have a very simple python/typer program.

i also use the poetry as build tool.

This is a snippet of my pyproject.toml file:

```
name = "cat-cli"
version = "0.1.3"
description = "Cat Cli"
```

Is there a simple way get the version number specified in the toml file into my python program?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

The canonical way of getting the version number of an installed package, is to use [importlib.metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#) or its backport [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) if you are on Python <3.8.

```py
try:
    from importlib import metadata
except ImportError:
    import importlib_metadata as metadata

version = metadata.version("mypackage")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a package like [tomli](https://pypi.org/project/tomli/) to read the poetry configuration file and get the version using something like:

```
import tomli

with open("pyproject.toml", mode="r") as config:
    toml_file = tomli.load(config)
```

`toml_file['tool.poetry']['version']` should get you the version string, assuming you have the tool.poetry table.

[Follow this guide to get you started](https://realpython.com/python-toml/#load-toml-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will show you the include flag to use for `arrayobject.h`

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from pathlib import Path

numpy_include_path = Path(np.get_include())
arrayobject_h = numpy_include_path / 'numpy' / 'arrayobject.h'

if arrayobject_h.exists():
    print(f"-I{numpy_include_path}")
else:
    print('arrayobject.h not found :-()')
```