# Get app version from pyproject.toml inside python code

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry, python-importlib

I am not very familiar with python, I only done automation with so I am a new with packages and everything.
I am creating an API with Flask, Gunicorn and Poetry.
I noticed that there is a version number inside the pyproject.toml and I would like to create a route /version which returns the version of my app.
My app structure look like this atm:

```
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── tests
│   └── __init__.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Where `wsgi.py` is my main file which run the app.

I saw peoples using importlib but I didn't find how to make it work as it is used with:
 `__version__ = importlib.metadata.version("__package__")`
But I have no clue what this **package** mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of the "\_\_package\_\_" attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233229/whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python)

Comment: Beyond your question about the meaning of `__package__` there are suspicious things in your question. -- You should not have a `__init__.py` right next to `pyproject.toml`, typically you would want to put all Python code in a sub-directory named after what you want your top-level import package to be.

Comment: @sinoroc Should I put my main file a the top or should I create a subfolder like "src" or something and put my main file inside?

Comment: @pgossa I recommend the so-called `src`-layout, but you do not have to. It's best if you let `poetry` create the project template with [`poetry new --src name-of-your-new-project`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#new).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not use `__package__`, which is the name of the "import package" (or maybe import module, depending on where this line of code is located), and this is not what `importlib.metadata.version()` expects. This function expects the name of the distribution package (the thing that you *pip*-install), which is the one you write in `pyproject.toml` as `name = "???"`.

So if the application or library whose version string you want to get is named `Foo`, then you only need to call the following

```py
import importlib.metadata

version_string_of_foo = importlib.metadata.version('Foo')
```

Comment: Ok thank you I just totally missed the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract version from `pyproject.toml` using [toml](https://pypi.org/project/toml/) package to read toml file and then display it in a webpage.

Comment: This will not work, because the `pyproject.toml` file will not be available once the project is _pip_-installed (you can also see that the file is not in the wheels).

Comment: @will.mendil https://stackoverflow.com/a/75100875

Answer (score 0):

In the `project.toml` you can specify version in different ways:

- [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/) expects version in the `[tool.poetry]`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
```

- [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) expects version in the `[project]` section:

```ini
[project]
name = "my-package"
version = "2020.0.0"
```

The next point is that you may want to see the version of installed packages (e.g. via `pip` or `poetry`) or your application. The next:

```py
import importlib.metadata

version = importlib.metadata.version("my-package")
print(version)
```

This code works fine with installed packages. To make working it with your project, you **should install** it using `pip install -e .` or something similar.

If you want to check version of your project **without installing**, then you can use the following snippet:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import toml

version = "unknown"
# adopt path to your pyproject.toml
pyproject_toml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "pyproject.toml"
if pyproject_toml_file.exists() and pyproject_toml_file.is_file():
    data = toml.load(pyproject_toml_file)
    # check project.version
    if "project" in data and "version" in data["project"]:
        version = data["project"]["version"]
    # check tool.poetry.version
    elif "tool" in data and "poetry" in data["tool"] and "version" in data["tool"]["poetry"]:
        version = data["tool"]["poetry"]["version"]
print(version)
```

To make it working you should install [`toml`](https://pypi.org/project/toml/) package in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question.

One of the solution I could come up is to ship the pyproject.toml file together with the project, as a data file. This can be done by putting pyproject.toml inside `your_package/data`, and put `include = [{path = "phuego/data/pyproject.toml"}]`under `[tool.poetry]` in pyproject.toml. Then, you can use `toml` package to access it.

But I'm not convinced by this solution. Perhaps there is a better idea out there.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34618319)

Comment: Bad idea. Just use `importlib.metadata.version('TheNameOfTheAppOrLibrary')`.

Answer (score -1):

I am doing this:

```
from poetry.core.factory import Factory

def display_version():

    __thisScript__ = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    __thisFolder__ = os.path.dirname(__thisScript__)
    factory = Factory()
    this_project = factory.create_poetry(__thisFolder__)
    print(f"{this_project.package.name} version {this_project.package.version}")
    print(f"{this_project.package.description}")

    sys.exit(0)
# end def
```

I also added the included statemetn the pyproject.toml file into my pyproject.toml file as mentioned by Haoqi Chen

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "myApp"
version = "0.1.5"
description = "A faster alternative to Windows `rmdir /s /q` for large directories."
authors = ["Joe B"]
readme = "README.md"
include = [{path = "./pyproject.toml"}]
```

I used a relative path to pyproject.toml as I always use poetry build from the same folder as pyproject.toml.

Comment: Why so complex when there are solutions available in Python's standard library already that are way more robust? Just use `importlib.metadata.version('myApp')`.